# can javafx media play mp4 format video files?

Tags: java, video, javafx-2, media

I am trying to play videos using javafx media. but I am unable to play video in local machine videos. I tried with default AdvancedMedia.java file javafx Ensemble.jar file. I copied same file code and pasted in my Eclipse. in that also playing few seconds and stooping. for few seconds. but instead of default media file location if I am giving any .mp4 format file in my local machine it not playing and also not giving error.

I am placing code below

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2012 Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * An advanced media player with controls for play/pause, seek, and volume. 
 *
 * @see javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer
 * @see javafx.scene.media.Media
 */
public class AdvancedMedia extends Application {
   private static final String MEDIA_URL =// "file:///D:/sri1/test.mp4";
    //private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";
    "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private AdvancedMedia.MediaControl mediaControl;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));


        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL));
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaControl = new AdvancedMedia.MediaControl(mediaPlayer);
        mediaControl.setMinSize(480,280);
        mediaControl.setPrefSize(480,280);
        mediaControl.setMaxSize(480,280);
        root.getChildren().add(mediaControl);
    }

    public void play() {
        Status status = mediaPlayer.getStatus();
        if (status == Status.UNKNOWN
            || status == Status.HALTED)
        {
            //System.out.println("Player is in a bad or unknown state, can't play.");
            return;
        }

        if (status == Status.PAUSED
         || status == Status.STOPPED
         || status == Status.READY)
        {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }
    }

    @Override public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public class MediaControl extends BorderPane {
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private MediaView mediaView;
        private final boolean repeat = false;
        private boolean stopRequested = false;
        private boolean atEndOfMedia = false;
        private Duration duration;
        private Slider timeSlider;
        private Label playTime;
        private Slider volumeSlider;
        private HBox mediaBar;
        private final Image PlayButtonImage = new Image("file:///D:/sri/UpgradeReport_Plus.gif");
        ImageView imageViewPlay = new ImageView(PlayButtonImage);
        //URI x=new URI("file:///D:/deepak/DEEP PHOTO.jpg");
        File f=new File("file:///D:/sri/UpgradeReport_Plus.gif");
        URI u=f.toURI();
        private final Image PauseButtonImage = new Image(u.toString());

        ImageView imageViewPause = new ImageView(PauseButtonImage);
        private Pane mvPane;
        private Stage newStage;
        private boolean fullScreen = false;

        @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
            if (mediaView != null && getBottom() != null) {
                mediaView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
                mediaView.setFitHeight(getHeight() - getBottom().prefHeight(-1));
            }
            super.layoutChildren();
            if (mediaView != null && getCenter() != null) {
                mediaView.setTranslateX((((Pane)getCenter()).getWidth() - mediaView.prefWidth(-1)) / 2);
                mediaView.setTranslateY((((Pane)getCenter()).getHeight() - mediaView.prefHeight(-1)) / 2);
            }
        }

        @Override protected double computeMinWidth(double height) {
            return mediaBar.prefWidth(-1);
        }

        @Override protected double computeMinHeight(double width) {
            return 200;
        }

        @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
            return Math.max(mp.getMedia().getWidth(), mediaBar.prefWidth(height));
        }

        @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
            return mp.getMedia().getHeight() + mediaBar.prefHeight(width);
        }

        @Override protected double computeMaxWidth(double height) { return Double.MAX_VALUE; }

        @Override protected double computeMaxHeight(double width) { return Double.MAX_VALUE; }

        public MediaControl(final MediaPlayer mp) {
            this.mp=mp;
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #bfc2c7;"); // TODO: Use css file
            mediaView = new MediaView(mp);
            mvPane = new Pane();
            mvPane.getChildren().add(mediaView);
            mvPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;"); // TODO: Use css file
            setCenter(mvPane);
            mediaBar = new HBox(5.0);
            mediaBar.setPadding(new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10));
            mediaBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            BorderPane.setAlignment(mediaBar, Pos.CENTER);

            final Button playButton  = ButtonBuilder.create()
                    .minWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE)
                    .build();

            playButton.setGraphic(imageViewPlay);
            playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    updateValues();
                    Status status = mp.getStatus();
                    if (status == Status.UNKNOWN
                        || status == Status.HALTED)
                    {
                        // don't do anything in these states
                        return;
                    }

                    if (status == Status.PAUSED
                        || status == Status.READY
                        || status == Status.STOPPED)
                    {
                        // rewind the movie if we're sitting at the end
                        if (atEndOfMedia) {
                            mp.seek(mp.getStartTime());
                            atEndOfMedia = false;
                            playButton.setGraphic(imageViewPlay);
                            //playButton.setText(">");
                            updateValues();
                        }
                        mp.play();
                        playButton.setGraphic(imageViewPause);
                        //playButton.setText("||");
                    }
                    else {
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                }
            });
            mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
                    updateValues();
                }
            });
            mp.setOnPlaying(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    if (stopRequested) {
                        mp.pause();
                        stopRequested = false;
                    } else {
                        playButton.setGraphic(imageViewPause);
                        //playButton.setText("||");
                    }
                }
            });
            mp.setOnPaused(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    playButton.setGraphic(imageViewPlay);
                    //playButton.setText("||");
                }
            });
            mp.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    duration = mp.getMedia().getDuration();
                    updateValues();
                }
            });

            mp.setCycleCount(repeat ? MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE : 1);
            mp.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!repeat) {
                        playButton.setGraphic(imageViewPlay);
                        //playButton.setText(">");
                        stopRequested = true;
                        atEndOfMedia = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            mediaBar.getChildren().add(playButton);

            // Time label
            Label timeLabel = new Label("Time");
            timeLabel.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            mediaBar.getChildren().add(timeLabel);


            // Time slider
            timeSlider = SliderBuilder.create()
                    .minWidth(30)
                    .maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE)
                    .build();
            HBox.setHgrow(timeSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
            timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
                public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                    if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                        // multiply duration by percentage calculated by slider position
                        if(duration!=null) {
                            mp.seek(duration.multiply(timeSlider.getValue() / 100.0));
                        }
                        updateValues();

                    }
                }
            });
            mediaBar.getChildren().add(timeSlider);

            // Play label
            playTime = LabelBuilder.create()
                    //.prefWidth(130)
                    .minWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE)
                    .build();

            mediaBar.getChildren().add(playTime);


            //Fullscreen button

            Button buttonFullScreen = ButtonBuilder.create()
                    .text("Full Screen")
                    .minWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE)
                    .build();

            buttonFullScreen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (!fullScreen){
                    newStage = new Stage();
                    newStage.fullScreenProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                            onFullScreen(); 
                        }
                    });
                    final BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(){
                        @Override protected void layoutChildren(){
                            if (mediaView != null && getBottom() != null) {
                                    mediaView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
                                    mediaView.setFitHeight(getHeight() - getBottom().prefHeight(-1));
                            }
                            super.layoutChildren();
                            if (mediaView != null) {
                                mediaView.setTranslateX((((Pane)getCenter()).getWidth() - mediaView.prefWidth(-1)) / 2);
                                mediaView.setTranslateY((((Pane)getCenter()).getHeight() - mediaView.prefHeight(-1)) / 2);
                            }
                        };
                    };

                    setCenter(null);
                    setBottom(null);
                    borderPane.setCenter(mvPane);
                    borderPane.setBottom(mediaBar);

                    Scene newScene = new Scene(borderPane);
                    newStage.setScene(newScene);
                    //Workaround for disposing stage when exit fullscreen
                    newStage.setX(-100000);
                    newStage.setY(-100000);

                    newStage.setFullScreen(true);
                    fullScreen = true;
                    newStage.show();

                }
                    else{
                        //toggle FullScreen
                        fullScreen = false;
                        newStage.setFullScreen(false);

                    }
                }

            });
            mediaBar.getChildren().add(buttonFullScreen);

            // Volume label
            Label volumeLabel = new Label("Vol");
            volumeLabel.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            mediaBar.getChildren().add(volumeLabel);

            // Volume slider
            volumeSlider = SliderBuilder.create()
                    .prefWidth(70)
                    .minWidth(30)
                    .maxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE)
                    .build();
            volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
                public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                }
            });
            volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    if (volumeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                        mp.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100.0);
                    }
                }
            });
            mediaBar.getChildren().add(volumeSlider);

            setBottom(mediaBar);

        }

        protected void onFullScreen(){
            if (!newStage.isFullScreen()){

                fullScreen = false;
                setCenter(mvPane);
                setBottom(mediaBar);
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        newStage.close();
                        }
                    });

            }
        }

        protected void updateValues() {
            if (playTime != null && timeSlider != null && volumeSlider != null && duration != null) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Duration currentTime = mp.getCurrentTime();
                        playTime.setText(formatTime(currentTime, duration));
                        timeSlider.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                        if (!timeSlider.isDisabled() && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO) && !timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                            timeSlider.setValue(currentTime.divide(duration).toMillis() * 100.0);
                        }
                        if (!volumeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                            volumeSlider.setValue((int) Math.round(mp.getVolume() * 100));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        private String formatTime(Duration elapsed, Duration duration) {
            int intElapsed = (int)Math.floor(elapsed.toSeconds());
            int elapsedHours = intElapsed / (60 * 60);
            if (elapsedHours > 0) {
                intElapsed -= elapsedHours * 60 * 60;
            }
            int elapsedMinutes = intElapsed / 60;
            int elapsedSeconds = intElapsed - elapsedHours * 60 * 60 - elapsedMinutes * 60;

            if (duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO)) {
                int intDuration = (int)Math.floor(duration.toSeconds());
                int durationHours = intDuration / (60 * 60);
                if (durationHours > 0) {
                    intDuration -= durationHours * 60 * 60;
                }
                int durationMinutes = intDuration / 60;
                int durationSeconds = intDuration - durationHours * 60 * 60 - durationMinutes * 60;

                if (durationHours > 0) {
                    return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d/%d:%02d:%02d",
                                         elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds,
                                         durationHours, durationMinutes, durationSeconds);
                } else {
                    return String.format("%02d:%02d/%02d:%02d",
                                         elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds,
                                         durationMinutes, durationSeconds);
                }
            } else {
                if (elapsedHours > 0) {
                    return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",
                                         elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);
                } else {
                    return String.format("%02d:%02d",
                                         elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        play();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Video extends Application{
     private String Dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
               launch(args);
     }

     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

     //goes to user Directory
    File f = new File(Dir, "Epic Lightsaber Duel - Star Wars_ The Force Awakens.mp4");


    //Converts media to string URL
    Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
    javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer player = new   javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView viewer = new MediaView(player);

    //change width and height to fit video
    DoubleProperty width = viewer.fitWidthProperty();
    DoubleProperty height = viewer.fitHeightProperty();
    width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(viewer.sceneProperty(), "width"));
    height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(viewer.sceneProperty(), "height"));
    viewer.setPreserveRatio(true);


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(viewer);

    //set the Scene
    Scene scenes = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scenes);
    stage.setTitle("Riddle Game");
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.show();   
    player.play();
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

To play local video use following

```
private static File file = new File("d:/videos/xyz.mp4");
private static final String MEDIA_URL = file.toURI().toString();
```

this works for me.
Hope this will help you.